# How can I make a responsive menu with diagonal grid in CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

i am creating a template for a website. there i want to create a menu like this
[image]

I found the below code as a solution

but I can't get the div to divided into 4 parts and add the text in a responsive way. Can do it using `position:absolute`, but the it is not responsive. How can I achieve this using css in a responsive way?

```css
.background {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.line1 {
  width: 112px;
  height: 47px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px) translateX(5px) rotate(27deg);
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -20px; */
}

.line2 {
  width: 112px;
  height: 47px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px) translateX(5px) rotate(-26deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can take it as a normal box with 2*2 grid, only having the inner borders to that 4 divs, and rotate them 45deg

Comment: Is it necessary to make the design same in mobile view as well? Can't we change it to list view on mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** & **CSS Transform** properties to achieve this. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-cover {
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
  padding: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(600px - 100px);
  height: calc(600px - 100px);
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.menu:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}

.item a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu-cover">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Bussiness</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Talent</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Group</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution, but not responsive.

Comment: thank you.this worked. but not responsive though. ill work about that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. You can implement your requirement in the same way. I have added `<span>` tags to show the text.

```css
.background {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.line1 {
  width: 112px;
  height: 47px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px) translateX(5px) rotate(27deg);
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -20px; */
}

.line2 {
  width: 112px;
  height: 47px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px) translateX(5px) rotate(-26deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <span style="float:left;padding-left:20%">Business
  </span>
    <span style="float:left;padding-left:5%">Team
  </span>
    <span style="float:right;padding-left:5%">Talent
  </span>
    <span style="float:left;padding-left:20%">Group
  </span>
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3z8q2k4/

Comment: Please don't use link-only answers, since the link can go down, and your answer will be in vain. In addition, this is not responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements like `before` and `after`. Kindly review the updated answer. Hope it is helpful to you.

```css
.background {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background:before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  background :red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:-200px auto 0;
}

.background:after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  background :green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:-200px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not responsive.